# I want to display date picker, start time and end time will come in one screen?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

i want to implement date picker, start time and end time picker in one screen.
and my screen show look like [my image should be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVdXf.jpg)
 with two time pickers

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps

1. create separate fragment screen
2. show separate custom date picker view for start and end date
3. show custom time picker below to date picker for start and end time.